# Error caused by importing files in Python

Tags: python

I'm having problems running my code due to some problem related to importing files (because in just one file it runs normally).

Example error: **NameError: name 'unstackPile' is not defined.**

- `pile.py`

```
class Pile:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
```

- `element.py`

```
import pile

class Element:
    ...
```

- `main.py`

```
from element import *
from pile import *

pile = Pile()
while True:
    print ("1. Stack pile.")
    print ("2. Unstack pile.")
    print ("3. Inform stack size.")
    print ("4. List pile.")
    print ("5. Exit.")
    option = int(input("Inform your option: "))
    if option == 1:
       number = float(input("Input real number: "))
       stackPile(pile, number)
    elif option == 2:
       unstackPile(pile)
    elif option == 3:
       print(f"Lenght elements is {lenghtPile(pile)} elements.\n")
    elif option == 4:
       listPile(pilha)
    elif option == 5:
        print("Exit...\n")
        print(f"Lenght elements is {lenghtPile(pile)} elements.\n")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid option, please enter a valid option shown in the menu.\n")
```

Comment: Where do you define `unstackPile`?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like unstackPile function is defined anywhere in the code you provided. That's why you are seeing this error. You have two options of fixing it

1. in main.py add

```
def unstackPile(_pile):
    # add code here
    pass
```

2. add method to the pile class and then call `pile.unstackPile()` in main

```
class Pile:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None

    def unstackPile(self):
        # add code here
        pass
```